# Can gentile couples be forgiven for adultery?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage, sin, sexuality

Are noahide couple partners allowed to "forgive" adultery (as a consumated act described by rambam for noahides)?

Comment: Do you mean, if the wife commits adultery, the husband doesn't have to divorce her?

Comment: yes, also rambam does define adultery as only natural way (vaginal for gentiles), so things a jew couple may consider adultery, in a gentile couple wouldnt even be considered as a sin/adultery, so it can be forgiven

Comment: Some laws of sexual morality are there for preserving the sanctity of Israel (see Ibn Ezra Shemot 2:1 for example). It seems this might be an avenue to explore towards answering this question.

Comment: As far as I know, the rule that a married woman who strayed can't return to her husband is only for Jews... I don't *think* it appears anywhere in the 7 laws ... is that your question?

Comment: well. So both things i said are no problems.

Comment: 1) other sexual acts that are not vaginal sex are not considered as adultery so they are not a sin, 2) if husband wants to forgive as they are not a jew couple, no problems too

Comment: @eeerrrttt nobody has answered your question yet. These comments are just thoughts. A proper answer should be awaitd

Comment: nobody answered